# An experiment to show sound waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, home-experiment

My 6 year-old son asked me to explain the sound barrier. I think I'm ready to explain, but I wanted to know if I could add a little homemade experiment to show visually how soundwaves are generated.

Problem is, I don't know how to show it with a simple enough experiment. Any hint will be great.

Comment: How about using an speaker? He can touch the cone and feel the vibration that produces sound. It's not visual seeing the wave but maybe a way to show what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to find if I've got such a speaker at home.

Comment: A speaker would distort water falling from a faucet to great effect.  Better still if you can somehow change the pitch of the sound, and the water falling from the faucet would change accordingly.  Definitely a good visual cue, though it may not go any further to explain why it is doing that.

Comment: Hey, that's nice ! I'll definitely try this one !

Comment: If he wants a supersonic experience a whip will do it :-)

Comment: If only I had one ;) But I have to explain to him how it works, before trying to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpovwbPGEoo) demonstration using the Ruben's tube set-up might help. I always found this to be one of the most exciting visual demonstrations of sound waves.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it's the nearest one from a "housemade experiment", though I can't make it in my small apartment :(

Comment: I prefer [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBZmyG-WqNo)

Answer (score 0):

Sound waves can be visualised, but I can not imagine how it could be made without special equipment. You can find many related photographs on the internet if you search for the "Schlieren photography".

Comment: If there is no simple way, I'll use an analogy with a rock and water.

Comment: A rock falling into water is a single event. You can, perhaps, better illustrate the sub- and super-sonic propagation when you move a tip of a stick over a still water surface.

Comment: even a simple liquid container  on a loud speaker will show the effect of sound waves. see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwMq8mmqgQ4

Answer (score 0):

I you have a small speaker then you could lay it down and put a small piece of paper on it.Although not visible to the naked eye, when the speaker is switched on , a small piece of paper placed on the speakers will serve a good way to visualize the movements of air particles. Also to give an idea of the intensity of sound waves the speakers can be brought close and taken farther away to show how the intensity decrease with distance.One of my favorite explanations on this topic is on Khan Academy. A very intuitive approach with logical reasoning in astonishingly lucid language.
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/mechanical-waves-and-sound/sound-topic/v/production-of-sound

Comment: Wow, I LIKE this explanation !

Comment: Also , if you don't have the equipment above you could always look for videos on YouTube. This video especially is great to understand beats and the interference of sound waves: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i886Lbjbl9k

Comment: You might have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wKX_IWZUTg